# Am I using “such” right?

Tags: adjectives, quantifiers, premodifiers

Are these right?

1. such amounts of money
2. such a lot of money
3. such an amount of money
4. such lots
5. such lots of people

Comment: I will add that this question might also have been posted on the English Language Learners Stack Exchange.

Comment: Yes. What makes you uncomfortable with them? Can you expand?

Answer (score 1):

These are highly dependent on context, and mean different things depending upon that context.

Such, when describing amounts, is really a word to mean to a high degree rather than great quantity.  (*i.e.* it is a qualitative word, not a quantitative word *per se*.)  People will use such in a similar manner to say things like *Such a shame!*  But, they don't mean it is a lot of shames added together, but rather a very large shame.

First let me dismiss the last two as sounding strange to a speaker of American English, then I will explain the contextual meaning of the others.

**Such amounts of money**  If you are trying to say, "Wow, this is a lot of money!" it is not quite right.  It can be said, but it doesn't sound great.

If you are using it in the sense of "Such amounts of money cannot be transferred without paying taxes on them."  Then, this is the correct usage.

**Such a lot of money** Again, this doesn't sound great standing on it's own (there is no verb, it is just a sentence fragment).  If, however, you say:  *That is such a lot money!*, then it sounds fine.

**Such an amount of money** See *Such amounts of money* the usage is essentially the same.

Again, keep in mind that these are all sentence fragments.  They all sound a little strange standing on their own.  There are people who speak that way, to be certain.  My grandmother would likely have said, "Such a lot of money!"  But, in reality what she was saying was *[That is] such a lot money!*

If you would like a better usage (at least in American English) we would say ***What*** a lot of money!,   ***What*** a large amount of money!  ***That*** is a lot of money!

*What* and *that* would be better utilized here than *such* to  a speaker of American English.

Comment: Is this right?    That a  lot of money

Comment: @nima_persian No, you need a verb there. It should be That is a lot of money. (Or That's which uses the contraction that's to mean that is)